# How do I change the Azure Logic App Frequency and Request type

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How do I change the Azure Logic App Frequency and Request type (Not programmatic ally)

[Frequncy and Request type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE8A8.png)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by Frequency and Request type?

Comment: Sorry for short description, added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing a screenshot! So the **REQUEST** and **FREQUENCY** info that you're seeing on the Overview section relate to the specific Trigger that you're using in your Logic App. Different triggers will show different info here depending on how they're designed to operate & work.

In your case, it looks like you're using one of [Logic Apps' built-in connector called Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres) which will trigger workflow in your Logic Apps whenever a request is received to its endpoint hence **manual** and **on-demand**.

To change this trigger, navigate to **Logic Apps Designer** view under **DEVELOPMENT TOOLS** in the Azure Portal as shown below:

[image]

Moreover, I recommend reading [Logic Apps' documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list) and finding more about [triggers and actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers); overall concepts behand Logic Apps. Hope this helps and goodluck with your journey on Logic Apps!